# conditional statement in protractor

Tags: protractor, conditional-statements

From a filtering list of items, I tried to click one item(SG11). The problem is the item sorting list and item names are kept changing. So I tried to code ..

```
$('.mat-input-infix.mat-form-field-infix').click();
        element.all(by.css('.mat-option-text')).then(function(viewName) {
            console.log(viewName.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < viewName.length; i++) {

        if (viewName [i] == 'SG11') {
            element(by.css('.mat-option-text')).click();
        }
        else{
                console.log('invalid');
        }
        }});
```

});

But it always executes the else statement.  What am I doing wrong in the if condition and also how to click on that particular item? please help

DOM

```
<mat-option class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-4" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false"><!----><span class="mat-option-text">
            SG11 
        </span><div class="mat-option-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple=""></div></mat-option>
```

SG11_mhk

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu6KM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one wrong place in your code as following:

```
element.all(by.css('.mat-option-text')).then(function(viewName) {
   // viewName represents all matched elements, 
   // rather than the text content of all matched elements

   if (viewName[i] == 'SG11') {  // therefor the if condition is no way to be True.
```

You can call `getText()` on `element.all()` to read all text of elements as below code:

```
$('.mat-input-infix.mat-form-field-infix').click();

let allOpts = element.all(by.css('.mat-option-text'));

allOpts.getText().then(function (viewName) {
    console.log(viewName.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < viewName.length; i++) {

        if (viewName[i] == 'SG11') {
            allOpts.get(i).click();
        }
        else {
            console.log('invalid');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `charAt(i)` will return **only one** char. Char will never equal to `SG11`;

2) Please, if you want check equality, use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: i used === and ==. no luck